# webdriver won't cooperate with firefox

Tags: firefox, selenium, webdriver

I have been trying to use WebDriver to run some front-end Selenium tests, but it is refusing to cooperate with my Firefox.  I try to start a new FirefoxDriver with no arguments, and get an error message.

It says

```
 Selenium.WebDriverException:  Failed to connect to FirefoxBinary(/usr/bin/firefox) on port 7055.
```

Then, it says:

```
 Disabling foreign installed add-on fxdriver@googlecode.com in app-profile.
```

I have not installed any add-ons since starting the VM I'm running this in.  What do these errors mean?

Comment: Two questions: 1) I Selenium running in headless mode? If so have you exported the display? 2) What are the versions of ff and firefoxdriver?

Comment: I don't know if it's in headless mode--the full extend of my code can be found here:

http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp

I'm just trying to get the sample working.  I believe I'm on Firefox 36, and Firefoxdriver is whatever gets inherited from the Maven dependency on Selenium version 2.0a5

Comment: That's pretty old selenium version. Firstboff all you need a new one (2.15) and a newer version of Firefox driver.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the compatibility between Firefox and selenium webdriver versions.